# How do I edit screenshot with preview for highlight and pointing?

Tags: preview, screen-capture

When I take a screenshot I usually need to **highlight** some section and **point** to it. With skitch it is quite simple,

[image: skitch]

But with preview I can't find an easy way to do these two tasks. The "Hightligh Seletion" button is extremely confuing. I never figure out how to use it highlight some selection like skitch.

[image: preview]

There is no highlight selection button (the pencil button) in apple manual too https://support.apple.com/guide/preview/annotate-an-image-prvw1501/11.0/mac/13.0 and I never figure out how to use it.

Finally I found the answer here https://discussions.apple.com/thread/250895032

> The highlighter is actually reserved for selectable text in a PDF —
> which is unavailable in an image capture.

Comment: What do you expect us to bring as an answer? I think you found the options to do that in Preview already.

Comment: Your first screenshot shows drawing, not highlighting.  What version of macOS are you using and what format are your screenshots set to (try on a PDF to see it in action)?

Comment: We probably already have some Q&A on site about alternatives to Skitch. I currently use shottr.cc

Comment: If you guys check apple manual about preview, there is no highlight selection button (the pencil button) in it https://support.apple.com/guide/preview/annotate-an-image-prvw1501/11.0/mac/13.0  and I never figure out how to use it. The fact that you guys just close my question and give me the comments like what @Thinkr gave makes me believe you don't use that button either.

Comment: @Redarm If you use shottr.cc as nohillside suggested (BTW, I used it too) that is highligh and another screentool I use (QQ) calls it highlight too. Bascially it is underline to highlight.

Comment: @nohillside thanks I use shottr.cc too but it is not free.

Comment: I finally found a silimar question here https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/368644/how-can-i-highlight-text-on-a-screenshot-using-markup-in-macos so if you guys want to close it the reason should be dupliacted not **"off-topic"**

Comment: @nohillside I have to say this is the second time my question was closed wrongly. The first time we also had some discussion.

Comment: I'm a bit confused now. The recommendation to close as duplicate came from you, in the comment above. And [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/405339/9058) fits perfectly, it also matches your own edit on the question above. What other answers would you expect?

Comment: Also, shottr.cc can be used without a license (["You can download and use Shottr for free. After 30 days it will start asking you to consider upgrading."](https://shottr.cc/purchase.html)).

Comment: @Qiulang 邱朗 "If you use shottr.cc as nohillside suggested (BTW, I used it too) that is highlight and another screentool I use (QQ) calls it highlight too" I don't use those and Preview calls this "Draw".  You can set your screenshots to be saved as PDFs and with text recognition in more modern operating systems, nothing stands in your way to highlight with Preview, or draw as you've demonstrated (so "unavailable in an image capture" does not sound right).

Comment: @nohillside I was refer to the first time this question was closed with the reason **off-topic**. I have to say I was kind of "angry" with that so I did some futher reseach and found the "duplicated"question. And for my word “this is the second time my question was closed wrongly” I was refer to another question.

Comment: @Redarm "You can set your screenshots to be saved as PDFs and with text recognition in more modern operating systems, nothing stands in your way to highlight with Preview, or draw as you've demonstrated", I just want a simple highlight function, I don't feel the need to go all the trouble to do what you mentioned.  So your suggestion does not sound right too.

Comment: @Qiulang邱朗 Just because you do not "feel the need", doesn't make my remark (not a suggestion) wrong.  Anyway, I just tried to ascertain your macOS capabilities earlier. Don't forget you'd asked the question: "How do I edit screenshot with preview for highlight and pointing?"